# Show that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cos(Nx)dx \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function on the interval $[a,b]$. Show that 
>   $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cos(Nx)dx \rightarrow 0$$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$ by approximating $f$ by a polynomial.

Since $f$ isn't necessarily differentiable, we cannot simply integrate by parts and take the limit. This integral looks like the Fourier cosine series for $f$ if we divide out the constant part. Therefore, I was thinking of perhaps using Bessel's inequality to conclude that these coefficients will go to zero assuming $||f||^2$ is bounded. However, I am not sure why we need to approximate $f$ by a polynomial. Doesn't $f$ being continuous already imply that $||f||^2$ is bounded and thus our Fourier cosine coefficients will go to zero?

Comment: I'm not sure why to make it that complicated. Just estimate the integral from above by replacing f with its maximum in the interval and from below with the minimum.

Comment: I think this can be deduced from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: @MaikPickl Do you mean $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)cos(Nx)dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}Mcos(Nx)dx$? This doesn't seem to work in general. I.e. take $f(x) = cos(Nx)$ and $a = -\pi$ and $b=\pi$

Comment: @user620842 First of all your $f$ shouldn't depent on $N$. But then it surely works. In fact it's one of the first things you prove about integrals: when $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ then $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\leq \int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities

Comment: And since $\int_{a}^{b}Mcos(Nx)dx=M\int_{a}^{b}cos(Nx)dx$ you can just compute the integral $\int_{a}^{b}cos(Nx)dx$ directly to get the desired result.

Comment: @MaikPickl it makes sense to me, but my professor gave the counterexample I listed. What was his rationale?

Comment: @user620842 Not sure what his rationales are since his counterexample is not a counterexample. You can compute it explicitly in this case.

Comment: Why can $f$ not depend on $N$? I believe that is where he is drawing the conclusion, as if you work out what he gave, you would get something like $\pi$<$0$. I am just perplexed how he would miss something so obvious when he has been doing this for 30 years.

Comment: Forget my comment. I found my mistake. It´s not true that $h(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x$ if you replace $f$ by the maximum since the cosine gets negative from time to time. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with you that Bessel’s inequality allows to get the conclusion.

However, you’re invited to use another route with Weierstrass approximation theorem, as the result stands for polynomials as can be shown by integration by part or using complex exponential.

Comment: So would you do something like $|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cos(Nx)dx - \int_{a}^{b}g(x)\cos(Nx)dx| < \epsilon$ where $g$ is a polynomial approximation to $f$, and then manipulate that to get the desired result?

Comment: Yes exactly. $\int f\cos Nx = \int (f-g)\cos Nx +\int g \cos Nx$.